# Blue Image from make_lupton_rgb

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, astropy

Getting a very blue image when trying to stack three bands of FITS images, not sure why blue is coming across more than the others and unsure how to adjust individually

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.visualization import SqrtStretch
from astropy.visualization import ZScaleInterval
from astropy.visualization import make_lupton_rgb
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

forCasting = np.float_()
r=fits.open('...Directory_to_file/Horsehead_Red.fts')[0].data
g=fits.open('...Directory_to_file/Horsehead_Green.fts')[0].data
b=fits.open('...Directory_to_file/Horsehead_Blue.fts')[0].data

r = np.array(r,forCasting)
g = np.array(g,forCasting)
b = np.array(b,forCasting)

stretch = SqrtStretch() + ZScaleInterval()

r = stretch(g)
g = stretch(b)
b = stretch(r)

plt.imshow(r, origin='lower')
plt.imshow(g, origin='lower')
plt.imshow(b, origin='lower')

lo_val, up_val = np.percentile(np.hstack((r.flatten(), g.flatten(), b.flatten())), (10, 80))

stretch_val = up_val - lo_val

rgb_default = make_lupton_rgb(r, g, b, minimum=lo_val, stretch=stretch_val, Q=0, filename="provafinale.png")

plt.imshow(rgb_default, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

#### The resulting image in question:

[image]

Comment: I am not at all familiar with all the astronomy stuff, but try checking `r.min()` and `r.max()`, and also for `g` and `b` both before and after contrast stretching to see if you have adversely affected the range for the blue channel.

Comment: My max and min values before stretching are r min: 188.0/ g min: 52.0/ b min: 123.0/ r max: 45542.0/ g max: 45497.0/ b max: 45525.0. After all the mins are 0.0 and all the maxes are 1.0